# start assync php command line script from another php process

Tags: php, ajax, console, console-application

the question really says it all.
I have a script that processes loads of data and may run for a few hours. To avoid time limit exceptions and locking the user to that specific process execution I need to start that script from console. The question is, how can i start a php console script from another php instance and leave it running assynchonously?

The assync part is not that important if there is no nice way to do it via php I can just use ajax to launch the starter script.

Using PHP 5.5, but this must be runnable using PHP 5.4

Comment: this is not an answer to your direct question, but you may want to solve your core problem by running your hours-long script in a workerqueue using something like beanstalkd and pheanstalk. alternately, you could fork a child process to do the stuff your script does using pcntl_fork()

Comment: Hi, thnx for your advice, just looked up pcntl_fork() and seems that it will not work for what I want to achieve. Using queue (rabbitmq) was my backup plan, but I was hoping for something simpler and less time consuming.